# Facebook JS SDK - manage_pages permission is not asked while login from Test user

Tags: php, angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook js sdk. In the scope, I have added "manage_pages" permission. But when I try to login with a test user, this permission is never asked to the user. But if i add other permissions like 'user_likes' or 'user_location', facebook asks those permissions to the test user while logging in. Here is the code i have used.

```
FB.login((loginResponse)=>{                                                          
                    if(loginResponse.authResponse)
                    {
                       //process data
                    }                    
                },{scope: 'manage_pages',return_scopes: true});
```

I have to make it work (asking manage_pages permission) before i submit my facebook app for Review for which the deadline is approaching on 31st July. As per facebook, "We need to see your app using manage_pages so we can see that it doesn't violate our policies. Upload a video screencast walkthrough using any method,".

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is your app in live or dev mode? It might need to be the latter for this to work now. (Have not seen it officially documented yet, but from my experience it does seem to make a difference with certain permissions. They probably want to close the loophole that apps are able to post via app role accounts in a production setting now.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CBroe. App is in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

"If the test user already accepted 'manage_pages' at some point, the permission won't appear."

I checked with a new test user and still the manage_pages permission was not asked. The reason is that, when we create a test page using a test user with graph API explorer, we have to give manage_page permission. So since the user already has manage_pages permission before creating a test page, it is not asking again when we login with that user from the application. When I removed the manage_page permission of the test user and tried, I got the manage_page permission popup.